# JSTree Ajax loading from json, rendering clicked node again, as first child

Tags: javascript, ajax, jstree

My MVC method takes an id parameter and returns a node and its immediate children.  Then click on on a child returns the node again with its children.

but this ends up looking like this (having clicked on child2)

ROOT

--child1

--child2

----child2

------child2a

------child2b

--child3

i can make the mvc method only return children and never the root, and this works, BUT i do need to have the root at the top of the tree initially.

this is my JS

```
 "json_data": {
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/sandbox/NodeTree/",
                "data": function (n) {
                    return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : id };
                },
                "progressive_render": true
            }
        }
```

Comment: all i can think of, is to detect in the JS if its the initial request by doing this.  return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : id, branchcall: (n.attr !== undefined) };

Comment: I don't understand, could you provide working jsfiddle?